# Show that if $f \neq 0$ and $x < y \Rightarrow f(x) \le \frac {f(y) - f(x)}{y - x } \le f(y)$ then $f$ is differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have the following problem :

> $f \neq 0$ satisfies $x < y \Rightarrow f(x) \le \frac {f(y) - f(x)}{y - x } \le f(y)$  then $f$ is differentiable

---

#### Try

For $h > 0, f(x) \le \frac {f(x +h) - f(x)}{h} \le f(x + h)$.

By squeeze theorem, $\frac {f(x +h) - f(x)}{h} \le f(x + h) \to f(x)$ as $h \to 0^+$, but this assumes continuity of $f$. I'm stuck at showing $f$ is continuous.

Comment: How exactly did you make this so unreadable?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)(y - x) \le f(y) - f(x) \le f(y)(y - x)$.
Thus as $x \to y, f(x) \to f(y).$

From such considerations and that $f$ is ascending,
continuity should be forth coming.